# Scala Async and Wartremover

Tags: scala, scala-wartremover

I wanted to use [scala-async](https://github.com/scala/scala-async).
I also use Wartremover with [Return] enabled. (http://www.wartremover.org/doc/warts.html#return).

Then I added some code to test it:

```
async {
  val studentsCount = await(studentsDao.getStudents())
  val externalStudentsCount = await(studentsDao.getExternalStudents())

  externalStudentsCount + studentsCount
}
```

When I try to compile it, it gives me error:

```
[wartremover:Return] return is disabled
```

Is there any way to use Wartremover with scala-async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the `async` macro generates `return` statement under the hood.

You can workaround it by adding `@SuppressWarnings(Array("org.wartremover.warts.Return"))` above the `async` block.

Comment: Adding `@SuppressWarnings` above every `async` block doesn't look very convenient.

Comment: That's all you can do, I guess. The most convenient is not to use `async` at all  but such answer would be off-topic. Wart remover helps to enforce ideomatic code and `async` is not ideomatic itself.

Comment: I don't use it, so `no-macros` didn't make it in. That would disable checks in macro expansions. https://github.com/wartremover/wartremover/pull/216

Comment: @som-snytt So basically you prepared PR for that, but it was not merged, because it was for wrong branch?

Comment: Maybe I'll try again; it fell off my radar because the action moved to scalafix for linting.